# Error in discussion of Job Search Status by Geography

Tags: bug, survey-2020

The discussion of the [Job Search Status by Geography](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#looking-for-a-job) states:

> In the US, India, UK, Germany, and Canada, over 80% of developers are not actively looking for a job, but at least half are open to new opportunities.

However, in the charts, the bar labels for "I am actively looking for a job" and "I am not interested in new job opportunities" are switched for India, so it appears that in India, nearly one-third of developers **are** actively seeking new employment.

[image: US Job Search Status]

[image: India Job Search Status]